# iTunes - Apple Music - songs are not playing

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I am using Apple Music. Most of the time, if I choose the song, it wont play. Progress bar is fully filled, but not music. Sometimes, it is also jagged (1 min play, 1 min not). What to do with that?

I am using Windows 7 SP1 x64.